# My DVD Rom is detected in BIOS and I can see that but in My Computer isn't available

Tags: windows, bios, dvd

My DVD ROM is detected in the BIOS, but it is not available in windows.
What can I do?

Comment: Is it an old fashion PATA DVD or a SATA DVD. If it is the first (PATA), then are the jumpers for single/slave/master set correctly?  (I have had a CDROM which was jumpered incorrectly, but the BIOS unfortunately picked it up. Windows didn't).

Comment: I have sata DVD. I can't find a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you add these things to your original post? 1) Which windows version.  2) If it is detected in the device manager (it might be disabled there. Or it might work fine and just does not have a drive letter assigned to it).  3) Is there anything marked with a yellow exclamation mark in the device manages (e.g. a chipset/SATA driver).  4) Is there anything about the CDROM in the event log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this way [This Site](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-25531-help-i-have-uninstalled-my-cd-dvd-rom-driver) and follow it. It was a best solution for me.

I was fixing a computer the other day and ran across the following error in Device Manager on the CD-ROM drive.

"Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware. The driver may be corrupted or missing. (Code 39)"

Because of this error, the drive did not show up in My Computer and the customer was unable to burn CDs or read any CDs.

I uninstalled the drive from Device Manager, rebooted the computer, and the problem remained, so obviously it appeared to be a registry issue that I would have to solve. If you are receiving this Code 39 error and your CD or DVD drive is missing and has a yellow exclamation mark in Device Manager, I hope this information is useful.

To solve this Code 39 error, follow these instructions:

NOTE: After removing these registry keys and rebooting, it may be necessary to reinstall any CD or DVD recording applications.

1) Close all open programs

2) Click on Start, Run, and type REGEDIT and press Enter

3) Click on the plus signs (+) next to the following folders

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
- SYSTEM
- CurrentControlSet
- Control
- Class
- {4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}

4) This folder is the DVD/CD-ROM Drive Class Description in the registry. Look for any of the following names in the right hand column.

- UpperFilters
- LowerFilters
- UpperFilters.bak
- LowerFilters.bak

5) If any of the above keys shown in step 4 are listed, right-click on them and choose Delete

6) After deleting the keys, close the Registry Editor

7) Reboot
your computer

8) Open My Computer and check to see if your CD or DVD drives have returned. You may also want to open Device Manager and verify that the yellow exclamation and error code on the CD or DVD drive is gone

Answer (score 2):

Reboot your system, login, and immediately take a look at Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer - see if something in the Application or System logs gives any clues.

Try reinstalling any burning software you have, such as Nero or Roxio.  If you installed any other software with your drive, try reinstalling that as well.

A copy-protection (or other) filter driver may be been installed when you inserted and let autoplay a disc, and that driver may be malfunctioning.  You may snag a copy of [Sysinternals' Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and look in the drivers section for any optical drive related drivers, and try disabling them.

If you have a Windows system restore point available at a point you know the drive worked properly, that may be an easy fix.

There's also a slight possibility that the drive may be actually recognized by Windows, but merely not assigned a drive letter.  Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Disk Management (or Winkey + R -> diskmgmt.msc to check that).

Answer (score 0):

My DVD drive appeared properly in the BIOS but nothing showed in Device Manager whatsoever. The whole UpperFilters/LowerFilters stuff didn't apply, because that only works if the drive is showing an exclamation mark. Anyway, what worked for me was to **uninstall all of the ATA/IDE controller entries** (I had three), then reboot. Windows reinstalled the drivers and my DVD drive magically reappeared!